# Redefine citename command for first author only

Tags: biblatex, citing

I try to redefine `\citename` command to print only first author's name (and *et al.* phrase) using the following code:

```
\newcommand\citefirstname{\AtNextCite{\defcounter{maxnames}{1}}\citename}
```

Unfortunatelly, the author names are now correctly abbreviated (i.e., only name of the first author is printed) but without *et al.* phrase.

Any idea what to do?

The MWE is pasted below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@article{Cohen2005,
  title={A survey of current work in biomedical text mining},
  author={Cohen, Aaron M and Hersh, William R},
  journal={Briefings in Bioinformatics},
  volume={6},
  number={1},
  pages={57--71},
  year={2005}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex} 
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\newcommand\citefirstname{\AtNextCite{\defcounter{maxnames}{0}}\citename}

\begin{document}
\citefirstname{Cohen2005}{author}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex-apa` has a very special default name format to conform with APA rules. So if you want to use `\citename` it is probably safer to explicitly request the `labelname` name format.

Note that `biblatex-apa` defines `\citeauthor*` to print the first name in `labelname`. Maybe that is what you are looking for.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newcommand\citefirstname{\AtNextCite{\defcounter{maxnames}{0}}\citename}

\begin{document}
\citefirstname{sigfridsson}[labelname]{author}

\citeauthor*{sigfridsson}
\end{document}
```

> Sigfridsson et al.
>
> Sigfridsson et al.